# Black & white horror: ski lift with something in clouds that killed you

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I'm looking for this black and white horror film I watched back in the 70s. It featured a ski lift, mountain top and these clouds, and there was something in the clouds that killed you. These films were on the TV, it was a feature called Monday night X-film. Can you help please?

Comment: Is it one film or several?

Answer (score 4):

I'm inclined to think this might be *[The Trollenberg Terror](http://bmoviefreak67.blogspot.com/2013/06/the-crawling-eye-1958.html)*, better known in some markets as *The Crawling Eye*.

> The film's storyline concerns journalist Philip Truscott investigating unusual accidents occurring near a resort hotel on a mountain near Trollenberg, Switzerland. United Nations troubleshooter Alan Brooks suspects these deaths are related to a series of similar incidents that happened three years earlier in the Andes mountains, which involved an unexplained radioactive mist and cloud formation.

It doesn't involve a ski lift, but it does involve a cable car, which is similar technology, but larger and enclosed.

[image: Film Poster[]

[image: Shot of the mountain with cloud]

[image: Long shot of the cable car ascending]

Comment: I think this must have been the inspiration for the Freakazoid episode "The Cloud". Huh!